# Obfuscating a number(in a string) Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, obfuscation

I'm using the following code to obfuscate a passcode for a test app of mine.

```
    - (NSString *)obfuscate:(NSString *)string withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // Create data object from the string
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Get pointer to data to obfuscate
    char *dataPtr = (char *) [data bytes];

    // Get pointer to key data
    char *keyData = (char *) [[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes];

    // Points to each char in sequence in the key
    char *keyPtr = keyData;
    int keyIndex = 0;

    // For each character in data, xor with current value in key
    for (int x = 0; x < [data length]; x++)
    {
        // Replace current character in data with
        // current character xor'd with current key value.
        // Bump each pointer to the next character
        *dataPtr = *dataPtr++ ^ *keyPtr++;

        // If at end of key data, reset count and
        // set key pointer back to start of key value
        if (++keyIndex == [key length])
            keyIndex = 0, keyPtr = keyData;
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

This works like a charm with all strings, but i've ran into a bit of a problem comparing the following results

```
NSLog([[self obfuscate:@"0000", @"maki"]); //Returns 0]<W

NSLog([[self obfuscate:@"0809", @"maki"]); //Returns 0]<W
```

As you can see, the two strings with numbers in, while different, return the same result! Whats gone wrong in the code i've attached to result in the same result for these two numbers?

Another example:

```
NSLog([self obfuscate:@"8000" withKey:@"maki"]); //Returns 8U4_
NSLog([self obfuscate:@"8290" withKey:@"maki"]); //Returns 8U4_ as well
```

I may be misunderstanding the concept of obfuscation, but I was under the impression that each unique string returns a unique obfuscated string!

Please help me fix this bug/glitch
Source of Code: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/obfuscation-encryption-of-string-nsstring.html

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with your implementation: I rewrote your code in C, and got different results for `"0000","maki"` and `"0809","maki"` ([see demo here](http://ideone.com/mQcfch)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your last line. You create the new string with the original, unmodified `data` object.

You need to create a new `NSData` object from the modified `dataPtr` bytes.

```
NSData *newData = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataPtr length:data.length];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But you have some bigger issues.

1. The calls to `bytes` returns a constant, read-only reference to the bytes in the `NSData` object. You should NOT be modifying that data.
2. The result of your XOR on the character data could, in theory, result in a byte stream that is no longer a valid UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: I'm testing it out now, do these two issues affect the result of the program in any way?

Comment: Sure. Your app could crash or give a `nil` result.

Answer (score 2):

The obfuscation algorithm that you have selected is based on `XOR`ing the data and the "key" values together. Generally, this is not very strong. Moreover, since `XOR` is symmetric, the results are very prone to producing duplicates.

Although your implementation is currently broken, fixing it would not be of much help in preventing the algorithm from producing identical results for different data: it is relatively straightforward to construct key/data pairs that produce the same obfuscated string - for example,

```
[self obfuscate:@"0123" withKey:@"vwxy"]
[self obfuscate:@"pqrs" withKey:@"6789"]
```

will produce identical results `"FFJJ"`, even though both the strings and the keys look sufficiently different.

If you would like to "obfuscate" your strings in a cryptographically strong way, use a [*salted*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) [*secure hash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) algorithm: it will produce very different results for even slightly different strings.

Comment: This is all excellent feedback but it's not actually an answer to the question. Perhaps this should be a comment.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree that this answer does not fix the OP's implementation. However, the algorithm is "broken" in a much more fundamental way - I provided more details in an edit.